# how to make a <div> height equal to combined height of its contents

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble finding a way to make a block like div in my page have its height automatically fit the height of its content, all these divs have a fixed width of 1000px and it's easy for me to set a right height for them as in pixels, but the size of the contents get changed a lot and it's frustrating to keep changing the div height as well.

Here is the existing css style for my divs

```
.start-block {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

and here is what inside of div look like:

```
<div style="float:right">
    <div class="start-description">
        <p>something</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="start-list">
        <li>stuff</li>
        <li>stuff</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: width: auto; doesn't work?

Comment: @T_D What does that have to do with the height?

Comment: sry, I meant height: auto

Comment: I don't understand the problem here, parent elements automatically expand to contain their children.  There's not enough code here to reproduce the problem you're claiming exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the div to have a height of 100%.  However, this will only be 100% of it's **parent** container.  So in your example, you'd also need the html/body tags to be 100%, like this:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

.start-block {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You can combine selectors that have identical properties: `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: well it didn't fixed much, i mean i don't want to make my block div big, mostly cuz there are other divs like it, i am looking for a way so that it's height be same as it's content, no more, no less

Comment: Oh, in that case, that's how divs just naturally work.  You must be doing something explicitly to break that, there's nothing in what you shared to indicate what.